# Mention who clicked the reaction after the bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I use `${reaction.message.author}` so the bot mentions the person who clicked on the reaction after it. But the bot is mentioning itself.

How to make the bot to mention the user who clicked on the reaction after the bot?

**===Code===**

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'Interpol')) {
    const response = args.join(' ');

    message.channel
      .send({
        content: '<@&776034311245660200>',
        embed: {
          color: 3447003,
          title: 'Новый вызов',
          timestamp: new Date(),
        },
      })
      .then((sentMessage) => {
        sentMessage.react('1️⃣');
        message.delete({ timeout: 100 });
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
          return ['1️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
        };

        sentMessage
          .awaitReactions(filter, {
            max: 2,
            time: 60000,
            errors: ['time'],
          })
          .then((collected) => {
            const reaction = collected.first();

            if (reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣') {
              console.log(reaction.message.author);

              message.author.send({
                embed: {
                  color: 3447003,
                  title: 'Вызов принят',
                  description: `**Сотрудник:** ${reaction.message.author}`,
                  timestamp: new Date(),
                },
              });
            }
          });
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your filter to filter out reactions if the `user` is a bot. This way the first reaction will be from a member:

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
  return ['1️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;
};
```

**Update:** So, you want to find the first member who reacted to the message and is not a bot. The problem is that you send a DM with `reaction.message.author`. [`reaction.message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=message) is the message that this reaction refers to, so the `sentMessage` in your case and the `author` of this message is the bot itself.

You can `.find()` the first member who reacted to the message by checking the `reaction.users.cache`. `reaction.users` is manager of the users that have given this reaction (including the bot). By using `.find()`, you can return a single member:

```js
message.channel
  .send({
    content: '<@&776034311245660200>',
    embed: {
      color: 3447003,
      title: 'Новый вызов',
      timestamp: new Date(),
    },
  })
  .then((sentMessage) => {
    sentMessage.react('1️⃣');
    message.delete({ timeout: 100 });
    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
      return !user.bot && ['1️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
    };

    sentMessage
      .awaitReactions(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: 60000,
        // errors: ['time'],
      })
      .then((collected) => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣') {
          // find the first member who reacted and is not a bot
          const member = reaction.users.cache.find((user) => !user.bot);

          message.author.send({
            embed: {
              color: 3447003,
              title: 'Вызов принят',
              description: `**Сотрудник:** ${member}`,
              timestamp: new Date(),
            },
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  });
```

Comment: I tried it, but the bot stopped responding.

Previously, he just mentioned himself, but now nothing

Comment: I think because you added `errors: ['time']` and `max: 2`. If only one member clicks on the reaction it will time out in 60 secs and that should be `catch`ed. Try to decrease the `max` value to 1, or remove the `errors` option.

Comment: Did, the bot keeps mentioning itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing a filter, if I'm not mistaken. This is a common occurrence when trying to collect something, the bot picks its own message/reactions to itself.

To correct this, all you have to add onto your filter function. `&& user.id === message.author.id;`

So:
`return ['1️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;`

This basically checks if the user who reacted was also the sender of the message, who I'm assuming is the bot. Else not, then you could just make it `!user.bot` to check if it's not a bot who responded like Zsolt said.